# Execute a trigger on the same table when updating

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to execute a trigger in phpMyAdmin-MySQL that includes an `UPDATE` statement on the same table, like this:

```
create trigger AFTER INSERT ON Table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Table
      SET Total = NEW.Total + 1.03
      WHERE order_number = NEW.order_number;
   END
```

Maybe, it is not possible to get this.  If not, is there any way to simulate this?

Comment: Can there be pre-existing rows with the same order number when you do the insert?

Comment: No, the order_number is a key column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a constraint that you can't update the same table in a trigger. However, if order_number is unique to the `INSERT`, I think you can achieve the same result by modifying the `Total` value in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total BEFORE INSERT ON Table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET NEW.Total = NEW.Total + 1.03;
END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f64190e5680c8d8d2f1340ed17323b6f)

Comment: No errors, but there is not changes in my Total column

Comment: @AlbertoMuñozSánchez I've added a demo showing it working for a simple example...

Comment: I think the problem is my phpMyAdmin interface.  I'm not familiar with it and I can't write the full code as you shown to me.  In fact, I get a syntax error if I copy it, and it works only if I just write `SET NEW.Total = NEW.Total + 1.03`.  How should I write it inside phpMyAdmin interface?

Comment: @AlbertoMuñozSánchez in phpMyAdmin you will need a `DELIMITER //` before you define the trigger, a `//` after the `END` and a `DELIMITER ;` after that.